# How to compute how many elements are adjacent in a 2D list

Tags: python, algorithm, list

So I have a 2D list with integers between 0 and 3. I need to calculate the highest number of adjacent nodes that are the same, but I just can't figure out how. An adjacent node is another node with the same value in a 3x3 square around the base.

Example:

```
[
 [1, 0, 0, 1]
 [0, 1, 0, 0]
 [1, 1, 1, 0]
]
```

should return 5 because (0,0) has one adjacent 1(1,1). (1,1) has 3 adjacent 1`s [(2,0),(2,1),(2,2)]. These counted together give 5.
(0,3) does not have any adjacent 1's and therefore has a score of 1 which is smaller than 5, so we return the highest score 5.

The function will have to work with a 10x10 2d list.

I would greatly appreciate help :)

Comment: Your example output is 5 as for 1 (the node let say in (1,1)) and 4 one's surrending? What are you time constraints? Did you tried brute force in `O(n*m)` (2D array size)

Comment: 0,0 has an adjacent 1(1,1) that has another surrounding 1 and so on, a few ms are OK

Comment: I still don't understand- can you please edit the question and explain why the output is 5?

Comment: Did it @dWinder

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have recommend on checking each cell while expending the search according the adjustment values. You can mark with `-1` cells that has been visited.

Consider the following pseudo code:

```
int getAdjNumber(x, y, matrix):
    val = matrix[x][y] // save current val
    matrix[x][y] = -1
    minX = max(0, x-1), maxX = min(matrix.len, x+1), minY = max(0, y-1), maxY = min(matrix.len, y+1) 
    sum = 1 // as current cell
    for i = minX to maxX
        for j = minY to maxY
            if matrix[i][j] == val
                sum += getAdjNumber(i,j, matrix)
    return sum
```

And main will be as:

```
max = 0
for each i,j :
    if matrix[i][j] != -1
        max = max(max, getAdjNumber(i,j, &matrix)) //sending as ref so the original matrix will be modify
```

Now `max` will be your output.

Notice this also support more values then just 1 or 0 - as your post said they may be 0-3.

Time complexity is `O(n^2)` - size of the 2D array - as each cell you count you change to `-1` so it cannot count again